# SQL Server 2012 LocalDB as WF4 Persistence storage

Tags: sql-server, workflow-foundation-4, localdb

Is it possible to use SQL Server 2012 LocalDB as a Persistence storage for Workflow Foundation 4.x? (4.0 or 4.5)?

I wasn't able to find any reference on MSDN about this kind of scenario.

Comment: of course.  The only difference between localdb and any other db is the connection string.

Comment: WF 4 uses some sql scripts to initialize, which will setup tables, stored procedures and maybe more. If nobody chimes in, I will try myself if it works as soon as I have time to setup a test env (too much to do lately.. :)

Comment: I'd chime in, but the answer is "yes".  Persistence scripts are just your normal tsql, will work on any sql server. localdb is just another type of sql server, so there's nothing to worry about. Try it out, add your findings as an answer with a couple images and close this out before anybody notices.

Comment: I was unable to upgrade from database 4.0 to 4.5 due to the requirement of SQL 2012 having a reference to the System.Activities.DurableInstancing.dll which I could not add due to the following error: 

Msg 6544, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'System.Activities.DurableInstancing' failed because assembly 'microsoft.visualbasic.activities.compiler' is malformed or not a pure .NET assembly. 
Unverifiable PE Header/native stub.

Apperantly SQL 2012 does not allow mixed CLRs to be added anymore.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer is simply yes